# How to define different variable in both development environment and production environment?

Tags: sinatra

like the remote server and port number, It's really annoying to change back and forth, I noticed there's a

```
set :environment, :production/:development
```

configuration option for sinatra, but I don't know how to set different variable to each mode

Answer (score 1):

you can have something like this:

```
configure :development do
  set :this
end

configure :production do
  set :that
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your settings are few:

For classic Sinatra apps:

```
port = 4567 if development?
port = 80 if production?
```

For modular Sinatra apps:

```
port = 4567 if Sinatra::Base.environment == :development
port = 80 if Sinatra::Base.environment == :production
```

But if you have several environment dependent settings, using three's suggestion above is cleaner:

```
configure :development, :test do
  port = 4567
  url = "https://secure.appname.com"
  ...
end
```